# How to use switch case in my case?

Tags: linux, shell, bourne-shell

My problem definition is : 1.Write a Bourn shell script dTOe which takes as an input any number between 0 and 999 and prints the English value for this number. I am struggling with above problem. Could you give me any hints or helps?

```
#! /bin/bash

number=$1

if [ $number -lt  0 -o $number -gt 999 ]
then
    echo put the right input between 0 and 999
fi

case "$number"
    [0-9])
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did it not work as expected or intended?  Have you read the manual page for the shell you're coding for?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use if statement first, like manually, to put every case such as from 0 , but I thought it looks like not the proper way, so I am trying to use switch case.. but cannot make a logic.

Comment: @GideokSeong, please, [edit] your question to add any details, and show us the code so we can see what it actually does!

Comment: @ilkkachu Sure, I am so fresh about using linux, so I haven't done much so far..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about how your thought process works for translating from digit form to prose form.  What do you look at first?  What do you do with that information?  Is there a pattern to your workflow that you could express in a procedural form?  How can this be broken into small, discrete steps which are analogous to the commands available to you?

The above line of thinking is the quintessence of programming and scripting.

One you have the skeleton of the process in mind, put it down in "pseudocode" - words that make sense to you, if not to the shell -- and step through that process, to make sure it does what you *want* rather than just what you *say*.  Then translate that from your native tongue into shell commands.

For instance, a good starting point might be to determine how many place values you have to indicate.  There are a couple of ways to do this that come immediately to mind:  "how many digits do we have", or "is the number greater than 99?  greater than 9?"  Or you could even work out a system doesn't need you to sort this out first.

In this case, the first thing you need is the ability to do some basic arithmetic in the shell, and comparative tests.  So:

Let's say we've read the number into a variable, `number`, and already sanity-checked it to make sure the user didn't enter `-53` or `3.14` or `albatross` or something we're not wanting to actually parse.  We can start with:

```
output=""
if [[ "$number" -gt 100 ]]; then
    # okay, we know $number is greater than 100
    hundreds=$((number/100))
    case $hundreds in
        1) output="one" ;;
        2) output="two" ;;
        3) output="three" ;;
        # et cetera
    esac
    number=$((number-100*hundreds))
fi
output="$output hundred"
```

And you can build from there.

Comment: if [ $number -gt 9 -o $number -lt 100 ]
        then
            case $number in
            10)echo Ten
            ;;
            11)echo Eleven
            ;;
            esac
        fi
Hi, I have some problem above code, that can print Ten but when I try to put 11, it does not show Eleven..Do you know the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "Enter number : "
read num

length=$(echo $num | wc -c)
length=$(( $length - 1 ))

echo "Your number $num in words : "
for (( i=1; i<=$length; i++ ))
do
   # get one digit at a time
    digit=$(echo $num | cut -c $i)
   # use case control structure to find digit equivalent in words 
    case $digit in
       0) echo -n "zero " ;;
       1) echo -n "one " ;;
       2) echo -n "two " ;;
       3) echo -n "three " ;;
       4) echo -n "four " ;;
       5) echo -n "five " ;;
       6) echo -n "six " ;;
       7) echo -n "seven " ;;
       8) echo -n "eight " ;;
       9) echo -n "nine " ;;
  esac 
done

 # just print new line
echo ""
```